# How to dynamic load hibernate Entity based on id and class name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm mapping an **existing database** that has a couple of tables with the following fields:
    Task (table)
    external_id int(100)
    class_name varchar(300)

Those fields represents a class hierarchy, they can be Group or User
A single table could have values like:

```
external_id  class_name
1            com.mycompany.User 
3            com.mycompany.User
1            com.mycompany.Group
```

The class hierarchy is this:

```
User extends TaskExecutor
Group extends TaskExecutor
```

One of the table in the database is `Task`

```
class Task{
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor
    ....
}
```

is it possible to configure Hibernate to instantiate the proxy for the proper class based on the `class_name` database attribute?

`User` and `Group` class have a separate table on the database

Answer (score 0):

You can create a typed class hierarchy with Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "main_table")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "class_name") // The column to store the type
public abstract class AbstractMainTable {
    // Your entity declaration here

    // The type must be declared with insertable and updatable to false
    // or it can be omitted completely if not necessary
    @Column(name = "class_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String className;

}
```

Then you can declare your extend

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extended_table")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "myClassType") // Optional, the type value stored in the column IF different from the real classname
public class MyClass extends AbstractMainTable {
    // This automatically inherits the fields from AbstractMainTable
}
```

Comment: please see my question again I have add more details. It's an exisitng database and User and Group tables already exists

Comment: Give a full example with at least two tables, their schema and data. Because right now I don't see how my answer doesn't fit.